# Pass React route component to parent component props function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

extremely new to react and forgive me if this sounds stupid, but I'm trying to work it out.

My component structure is like this:

- Dashboard

  - Billing
  - Invoice

I want it so that when you click on an invoice link inside billing the Invoice component is rendered inside a div that lives in Dashboard.

- Dashboard <<<<

  - Billing ____^
  - Invoice >>>

I don't know if my approach is correct and I've gotten something wrong or if it is totally off and I need to rethink my understanding.

DASHBOARD:

```
<Route
    path="/dashboard/billing"
    render={() => (
        <Billing
            togglePanel={this.togglePanel}
            fillPanel={this.fillPanel}
        />
    )}
/>

BILLING:

<Route
    path="/dashboard/billing/invoice/:id"
    render={props => (
        <Invoice {...props} />
    )}
/>

Inside billing there is a list of Links as:

<Link
    onClick={event => {
        this.props.togglePanel();
    }}
    className="item"
    to={`/dashboard/billing/invoice/${d.id}`}
>
    View
</Link>
```

So we're clear I'm using:

import { Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";

Inside the Dashboard I have a div that I want to fill with the invoice component.

The fillPanel() func changes the state within Dashboard which in turn changes the content of the target div to whatever is passed (this is just my attempt).

I know how to display and hide on toggle etc so that's not the issue, I just want to know how fill the target div inside Dashboard with the Invoice component when it is rendered after clicking an item inside Billing.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to render a route for your use case. As far as I get it, you just need to show the `Invoice.js` in a div, whenever you click a link (from a list of links) in your `Billing.js`.

What you can do is instead of:

```
<Link
  onClick={event => {
    this.props.togglePanel();
  }}
  className="item"
  to={`/dashboard/billing/invoice/${d.id}`}
>
  View
</Link>
```

Use:

```
<div 
  onClick={event => {
    this.props.togglePanel();
  }}
  className="item"
> View 
</div>
```

And, instead of:

```
<Route
  path="/dashboard/billing/invoice/:id"
  render={props => (
    <Invoice {...props} />
  )}
/>
```

Use:

```
<div className="div-where-you-want-to-show-the-invoice">
  <Invoice {...props, d.id}/>
</div>
```

Comment: This does work, and thanks for that BUT, I want the user to be able to copy a link to the particular invoice, hence me using routes. Obviously I can push the route with history but when a user accesses the url how can I make it open?

Comment: In that case:
1: call the same component on the invoice route as well.
2: in your `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, read the route params.
3: use the route params to accordingly fetch/open your invoice in the `div-where-you-want-to-show-the-invoice`